# Irregular, non-contiguous Periods in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I need to represent a sequence of events.  These events are a little unusual in that they are:

- non-contiguous
- non-overlapping
- irregular duration

For example:

- 1200 - 1203
- 1210 - 1225
- 1304 - 1502

I would like to represent these events using `Pandas.PeriodIndex` but I can't figure out how to create `Period` objects with irregular durations.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to create `Period` objects with irregular durations using existing Pandas functionality?
2. If not, could you suggest how to modify Pandas in order to provide irregular duration `Period` objects?  ([this comment](http://blog.adamdklein.com/?p=582#comment-480057032) suggests that it might be possible "*using custom DateOffset classes with appropriately crafted onOffset, rollforward, rollback, and apply methods*")

#### Notes

1. The docstring for `Period` suggests that it is possible to specify arbitrary durations like `5T` for "5 minutes". I believe this docstring is incorrect. Running `pd.Period('2013-01-01', freq='5T')` produces an exception `ValueError: Only mult == 1 supported`.  I have reported [this issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4699).
2. The ["time stamps vs time spans" section in the Pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#time-stamps-vs-time-spans) states "*For regular time spans, pandas uses `Period` objects for scalar values and `PeriodIndex` for sequences of spans. **Better support for irregular intervals with arbitrary start and end points are forth-coming in future releases**.*" (my emphasis)

## Update 1

Building a `Period` with a custom duration looks pretty straightforward.  **BUT** I think the main stumbling block will be persuading `PeriodIndex` to accept `Periods` with different `freqs`.  e.g.:

```
In [93]: pd.PeriodIndex([pd.Period('2000', freq='D'), 
                         pd.Period('2001', freq='T')])

ValueError: 2001-01-01 00:00 is wrong freq
```

It looks like a central assumption in `PeriodIndex` is that every Period has the same `freq`.

Comment: I think it's best to keep periods periodic, i.e., regular. We might call what you are looking for, say, a "time span." How would a period help here? Could you, for example, make a 'start' column and an 'end' column for each of your spans? Please back up and explain what you are trying to accomplish with your data.

Comment: Hi Dan.  Thanks for the very quick reply.  Your suggestion is very similar to what I'm now planning to implement: I plan to use a `DataFrame`. Each row will represent a single event.  The index will represent the start time of each event and the there will be an `end` column to represent the end time of each event.  To back up and explain my end goal: I'm writing a 'feature detector' which runs through a timeseries dataset and identifies 'features' in this raw data which can last varying durations.

Comment: I have a similar problem although my periods are regular, I cannot create periods with the durations I need - e.g. '5000T'

Comment: I found this in the Pandas docs. This problem seems to be known. "For regular time spans, pandas uses Period objects for scalar values and PeriodIndex for sequences of spans. Better support for irregular intervals with arbitrary start and end points are forth-coming in future releases." http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#time-stamps-vs-time-spans

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution, depending on the application, is to bin your data by creating a PeriodIndex that has a period equal to the smallest unit of time resolution that you need in order to handle your data and then divide the data amongst the bins for each event, leaving the remaining bins null.

Comment: This would unfortunately be very inefficient if that "smallest time unit" be very small.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a time period of minutes you must pass date time include minutes like follow:

```
pd.PeriodIndex([pd.Period('2000-01-01 00:00', freq='T'), 
                     pd.Period('2001-01-01 00:00', freq='T')])
```

the result:

```
PeriodIndex(['2000-01-01 00:00', '2001-01-01 00:00'], dtype='period[T]', freq='T')
```